# Selecting a distinct row for a group

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Can anyone please tell me how to select the record with the minimum value in column C3 for each distinct value in column C1, but if the values are same in C3, then the record with the value 'x' in column c2 should be selected.  For example for the values inserted below I want to see the first and the third row. Many thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE Test.tst (
    C1  nvarchar(3) NOT Null,
    C2  nvarchar(3) NOT Null,
    C3  int not null)

Insert into test.tst
select 'A', 'x', 2 union
select 'A', 'y', 2 union
select 'B', 'x', 1 union
select 'B', 'y', 2
```

Comment: Why do you have this tagged as SQLServer **and** Oracle? Which RDMS are you using?

Comment: The syntax strongly suggests SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general answer to your question is to use `row_number()` with a clever `order by`:

```
select c1, c2, c3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by c1
                                order by c3 asc, (case when c2 = 'x' then 1 else 0 end) desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from tst t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d1f95) is a working SQL Fiddle.

Comment: gordon, i am getting several errors when i run your query in sql server. `The column prefix 't' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.`

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev . . . I'm confused.  Are you the original poster?  I guess Stack Overflow doesn't update the name on the question when the user name gets updated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Gordon, I am a learner. I like to test queries. I have not change my name. My name Borat Sagdiyev and always will be. Chenqui.

Comment: Gordon, can you please tell me what this does - `case when c2 = 'x' then 1 else 0 end` ? thanks.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev, this is a `case` statement, it is essentially an if statement in SQL. So if the value for the column `c2` is the letter x then the value of the new column is 1 otherwise it's 0. Gordon has included this in the `order by` to sort it properly. Since it's new to you, I'd suggest learning it in a select statement like `select CASE when yourCol = 'a value' then 'result1' else 'result2' end from ...`

Comment: With a slight correction, changing from tst to Test.tst, it worked very nicely. Thank you Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
select C1, min(C2) as C2, min(C3) as C3 from test group by C1
```

EDIT: Added [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fbbb3/3)

Comment: this doesn't take into account the `if the values are same in C3, then the record with the value 'x' in column c2 should be selected`

Comment: Did you try to run this? It most certainly does that that into account. putting c2 in a `min()` will always choose X over Y when doing a group by due their positions in the alphabet

Comment: @NathanKoop . . . This solves the problem for the test data given in the question.  This solution clearly doesn't work for different data, consistent with the question (such as `col2 = 'a'`).  It is up to the OP to decide if this is useful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are correct that it does solve for the data provided, but my comment was to clarify that the given answer did not solve all the requirements (per my reading of the question, which may be incorrect, it's a bit confusing).

Comment: @mituw16, your answer solves it correctly, for the current values, but if you change the values slightly (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a74e/1), then it appears as though your answer does not work (given my understanding of the requirements).

Comment: Perhaps my requirement was a bit unclear but 'x' is a fixed string  value that may not work with the Min function. For example if x='Moodys' and y='Fitch' then I want Moodys to be selected.